# Dynamically change material-dropdown-selection options using searchbox with keyup event in AngularDart

Tags: angular-dart

I have a dropdown menu with a search box to select out of about 1000 Options which are hierarchical. I begin to show top categories 1, 2, 3 in the dropdown. If you enter, say '1' a filter I implemented will now show subcategories 11, 12, .. of 1 only. This filter is called using keyup event on material-select-searchbox. I get a 'Expression has changed after it was checked'.

I suspect I get this error because I cannot modify parent input params just like that. I tried to solve the problem implementing the event handler in the parent component, modifying a parent variable (StringSelectionOptions categories in categories-selector.dart) that is an input to the material-select-searchbox (in categories-selector.html) - but this does not work.

I also tried fiddling around with @ViewChild but - without proper results.

I heard about StreamController and EventBusses, but I am not sure how to use these to solve my problem using library components (i.e. MaterialDropdownSelectComponent and MaterialSelectSearchboxComponent).

categories.dart

```
class Categories {
  static final List<Category> categories = [
   ["1", "", "Category 1"]
   ["2", "", "Category 2"]
   ["11", "1", "Category 11 - Subcategory of 1"]
   ["12", "1", "Category 12 - Subcategory of 1"]
   ["21", "2", "Category 21 - Subcategory of 2"]
   ["22", "2", "Category 22 - Subcategory of 2"]
   //... a thousand more ...
  ].map(
      (c) => Category(c.first, els[1], els.first + " " + els.last)
    ).toList();

  List<Category> filter(String searchterm){
    return categories.where( (nc) => 
      nc.parent == parent ).map((nc) => nc).toList();
   }
} 

class Category implements HasUIDisplayName {
  String code;
  String parent;
  String label;

  Category(this.code, this.parent, this.label);

  @override
  String toString() => label;
}
```

categories-selector.dart: imports

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_select/material_dropdown_select.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_select/material_select_searchbox.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/model/selection/string_selection_options.dart';
import 'package:right_scenario_explorer/src/activity_editor/scope_collapse_mixin.dart';
import 'package:right_scenario_explorer/src/company/activity.dart';
import 'package:right_scenario_explorer/src/company/emission.dart';
import 'package:right_scenario_explorer/src/utils/formatter.dart';
import 'package:right_scenario_explorer/src/utils/nace_codes.dart';
```

categories-selector.dart: code

```
@Component(
  exports: [Formatter, Categories],
  selector: "categories-selector",
  templateUrl: "categories-selector.html",
  directives: [
    coreDirectives,
    MaterialDropdownSelectComponent,
    MaterialSelectSearchboxComponent,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialIconComponent,
  ]
)
class CategoriesSelector extends OnInit with {

  @Output()
  Category selectedCategory;

  StringSelectionOptions<Category> categories;

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    getCategoryOptions("");
  } 

  void getCategoryOptions(String searchterm) {
    Categories categories = new Categories();
    var selectedOptions = categories.filter(searchterm);
    categoryOptions = StringSelectionOptions(selectedOptions);
  }

  void categorySearchBoxEventHandler(dynamic event){
    getCategoryOptions(event.target.value);
  }

  void updateSelectedCategory(Category category) {
    selectedCategory = category;
  }
}
```

categories-selector.html

```
<div>
<material-dropdown-select
    buttonAriaRole="combobox"
    [buttonText]="selectedCategory == null ? 'None' : selectedCategory.toString()"
    [options]="categories"
    (selection)="updateSelectedCategory($event)"
    [listAutoFocus]="false"
    [activateFirstOption]="false"
    <div header>
        <material-select-searchbox
            (keyup)="categorySearchBoxEventHandler"
            label="Search..."
            [filterable]="categories">
        </material-select-searchbox>
    </div>
</material-dropdown-select>
</div>
```

I would like to know how I can modify the options of material-dropdown-select from the keyup event of the material-select-searchbox. Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [material-auto-suggest-input](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_auto_suggest_input)
that has been made to dynamically update options when you enter a value.